# Flutter app crashes when requesting location on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, geolocation, flutter-dependencies

I am using the [Geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) plugin version 6.1.7.

When I try to request the current location, my app abruptly closes without any exception.
Debug Console says `Lost connection to device. Exited (sigterm)`

This only happens on iOS (physical device and simulator). This function runs fine on the android simulator as well as a physical device.

Here's the code:

```
Future<bool> getLocation(bool refresh) async {
position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();

if (mapPosition == null || refresh) {
  mapPosition = position;
}

return true;

}
```

Crashes at the `getCurrentPosition()` function.

I have added the required permissions in the Info.plist file.

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your location is required to show you relevant meals in your area.</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your location is required to show you relevant meals in your area.</string>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

**Edit:**

I have made sure that the app has permission granted. The location's permission level is 'While Using the App' in the Settings. Also made sure my location is on in the Settings.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your app has permission to use location on the device/emulator?

Comment: Yes I have. I have full permission. I have also went into the iphone's Settings to ensure the app has the highest level of permission.
I forgot to add that in the question. Will add now.

Comment: I don't see anything here that should cause this issue. Are you sure it's due to the `getCurrentPosition` call? Can you run the app on iOS without that line?

Comment: Yes I can run it fine without the line.

For testing purposes im running the app with a mockup location:
    //position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
    position = Position(latitude: 33.8600217, longitude: -78.039695);

Above works fine.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code and descriptors you have shared. Double check Info.plist for any typos or indention errors. Run flutter clean as well. The problem is definitely do to a lack of access to GPS on iOS somewhere. You just have to track down where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

I explored the Info.plist to find any abnormalities and noticed that there was an item for Background Location updates.

`<key>EnableBackgroundLocationUpdates</key> <true/>`

I got rid of this line and the crashing problem went away.

Hope this helps anyone else that experiences something similar.

Comment: Didn't work for me (Flutter 2). The only location in info.plist just this: 
 <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
 <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) location use</string>. That's because Apple want it.

Comment: @Saqlain Hi I have the same case like yours, and I have added ```<key>EnableBackgroundLocationUpdates</key> <true/>``` like your solution, at first it works fine, and then crash again ```Lost connection to device.``` Did you add something else after that? like ```pod update``` or something?

Comment: @Saqlain I would like to ask you, did you also enable ```Location Updates``` in Xcode ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but I was able to resolve it by adding background mode permission to my info.plist file, just like this.

```xml
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>location</string>
    </array>
```